# Как изменить язык в окне "Tools and Features" в Visual Studio 2022?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

Как изменить язык в этом окне? Вижла у меня на английском, но почему-то это окно открывается локализованным на русский. Я попытался полностью убрать русский язык и оставить только английский в языковых пакетах, но это не помогло

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Это не Visual Studio, а Visual Studio Installer. На него не распространяются настройки языка Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Необходимо перейти в папку где находится инсталлер (по умолчанию это `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer`)
2. Открыть cmd и выполнить: `vs_installer.exe --locale en-US`